# Angular: Unable to find the index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a controller which looks like this:

```
MyControllers.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.meta = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemName;

        console.log($scope.whichItem);
    }).error(function() {
        alert('Unable to get back informations :-(');
    });

    $scope.title1 = [{"title":"Redhat Theme Guide"}];
    $scope.title2 = [{"title":"Debian Theme Guide"}];
}]);
```

And a JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "category":"category1",
    "link":"category1",
    "expand":false,
    "keyword":"category1, category1 online, category1 something"
  },
  {
    "category":"category2",
    "link":"category2",
    "expand":false,
    "keyword":"category2, category2 online, category2 something"
  }
]
```

And I can't get data from that array with `{{meta[whichItem].keyword}}` because `whichItem` variable doesn't represent the index of the array. It's always a string but it should be integer: in this example either `0` or `1`. I tried `parseInt()` with `slice()` but with no success.

Comment: Once you received the data, the JSON is parsed in to an array of objects. So your issue has nothing to do with JSON. What exactly are the values of `whichItem`.

Comment: Console log indicates that the values are: **category1** and **category2** depends on my url... I need them to be **0** and **1**

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to search through array and if I find category's value matches my **$scope.whichItem** then use object **keyword** from that index...

Comment: Have you tried to assign data.data in the callback? The $http callback parameter is a response object, not solely the data response itself. Interesting to note you can access an array item by string or number, arr[1] is the same as arr['1'].

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Angular injects something like this: `<h1 class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" ng-model="meta"></h1>`. So there is nothing inside the tag **h1**. There should be some data from data.json

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution in my opinion would be to write a simple function to get an item from the array by searching for the specified category.
I use lo-dash quite a lot, it's very useful, so here's an example using that library.

JS:

```
$scope.getMetaDataByCategory = function(categoryId){
  return _.find($scope.meta, {category: categoryId});
};
```

HTML:

```
{{getMetaDataByCategory(whichItem).keyword}}
```

You can do this with a regular for loop too, but it's more code.

Comment: Look, this is exactly what I'm trying to achive and it should work as there is an example on Angular's webpage: [https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07]